# Am I programming my JavaScript web animation correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frameworks

So I am building a website that requires web animations, and in my initial development, I used jQuery to build the animations, however I have been told that jQuery is becoming old practice, and have decided to switch over to vanilla JavaScript, however I am not sure if I am using the best practice to do so. As such, here is my code:

```
window.onscroll=function top(){
    var totalDuration=250;//total desired duration of animation
    var img=document.getElementById("image");
    var objective=document.getElementById("objective");
    var header=document.getElementsByTagName("header");
    var newHeaderHeight=.25*window.innerHeight;
    var newImageMargLeft=.15*window.innerHeight;
    var newImageMargTop=.01*window.innerHeight;
    var origHeaderHeight=window.getComputedStyle(header[0],null).getPropertyValue("height");
    var origImageMargLeft=window.getComputedStyle(img,null).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
    var origImageMargTop=window.getComputedStyle(img,null).getPropertyValue("margin-top");
    origHeaderHeight=origHeaderHeight.substring(0,origHeaderHeight.length-2);
    origImageMargLeft=origImageMargLeft.substring(0,origImageMargLeft.length-2);
    origImageMargTop=origImageMargTop.substring(0,origImageMargTop.length-2);
    var headerFactor=((newHeaderHeight-origHeaderHeight)/totalDuration);
    var imgMargLeftFactor=((newImageMargLeft-origImageMargLeft)/totalDuration)*5;
    var imgMargTopFactor=((newImageMargTop-origImageMargTop)/totalDuration)*5;
    var id=setInterval(func,250);
    function func(){
        if (window.scrollY>window.innerHeight*.1){
            if (header[0].style.height===newHeaderHeight){
                id=clearInterval();
            }
            else{
                header[0].style.height=window.getComputedStyle(header[0],null).getPropertyValue("height").substring(0,window.getComputedStyle(header[0],null).getPropertyValue("height").length-2)-headerFactor;
                img.style.marginTop=window.getComputedStyle(img,null).getPropertyValue("margin-Top")-imgMargTopFactor;
                img.style.marginLeft=window.getComputedStyle(img,null).getPropertyValue("margin-Left")-imgMargLeftFactor;
                console.log("Header: "+(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(header[0],null).getPropertyValue("height").substring(0,window.getComputedStyle(header[0],null).getPropertyValue("height").length-2)))-4);
                console.log("Margin Top: "+typeof(4));
                console.log("Margin Left: "+img.style.marginLeft);
            }
        }
```

I know it looks very chaotic, and that was what I was afraid of.

I am essentially trying to animate a header bar that collapses after the scroll bar scrolls past a certain point. However I have multiple elements inside of it that I want to collapse and manipulate, and not just keep it to scale (i.e. change margins when collapsing, and set back to original when expanding, all of which is to be done simultaneously and, from the user's perspective, evenly.

A follow up question I have is, is it worth doing it in vanilla JavaScript? Or should I learn a framework? If so, which one, and why use a framework over vanilla JavaScript, even after all of my research, I am struggling to see why it is so important to learn these frameworks for web development, if they are built off of JavaScript in the first place (in reference to vue or react, etc.)

Comment: Hey there. Wow, I think I need glasses to read that. Have you heard of the Web Animations API? ([mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API)). It's not only much, *much* cleaner than this; it also takes advantage of efficiencies that you're just losing by iterating your own style changes. It's available in Chrome, Firefox and Opera and there is a light polyfill that works in all other major browsers.

Comment: Is this a part of vanilla JS?

Comment: yep. It's a working draft but the API is, I believe, stable. I use it in production where extensive browser support is a requirement.

Comment: Also setting up a new interval timer on every "scroll" event will cause the browser to bog down almost immediately, because "scroll" events are fired *very* rapidly when you're scrolling a page up and down.

Comment: Also also to use `clearInterval()` you need to *pass* the timer id: `clearInterval(id);`

Comment: Your "solution" is overcomplicated. I believe things could be done with 1 event handler and couple of CSS transitions. Please add a snippet or jsfiddle to show us what's going on. It would help to simplify your code.

Comment: I used the Javascript web animations as suggested by @Fissure King, however the animation keeps resetting after the animation runs . I replaced all of the above code with the web animations version. How do I prevent it from resetting, and how do I only allow it to occur only once when the scroll is less than 10% of the window width, and only once when it is above?

Comment: @Sal, add `fill: 'forwards'` to your options. Edit: see [`EffectTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EffectTiming) documentation.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!